# async behaviour in Fsharp

Tags: asynchronous, f#

When running the following code

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control

type Message(id, contents) =
    static let mutable count = 0
    member this.ID = id
    member this.Contents = contents
    static member CreateMessage(contents) =
        count <- count + 1
        Message(count, contents)

let mailbox = new MailboxProcessor<Message>(fun inbox ->
    let rec loop count =
        async { printfn "Message count = %d. Waiting for next message." count
                let! msg = inbox.Receive()
                printfn "Message received. ID: %d Contents: %s" msg.ID msg.Contents
                return! loop( count + 1) }
    loop 0)

mailbox.Start()

mailbox.Post(Message.CreateMessage("ABC"))
mailbox.Post(Message.CreateMessage("XYZ"))

//System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
Console.WriteLine("Press any key...")
Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
```

I get the following result

```
> Press any key...
Message count = 0. Waiting for next message.
Message received. ID: 1 Contents: ABC
Message count = 1. Waiting for next message.
Message received. ID: 2 Contents: XYZ
Message count = 2. Waiting for next message.
```

I would expect the msg press anykey to come somewhat after the first message...

And if I include the sleep, it indeed comes after.

So my question is :

**Is the take away lesson** of this that you can not expect any particular ordering when using async methods. aka, the **code inside async can start with no specific precedence** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs for `mailboxProcessor` (where this code sample is from)

> `Post`
>
> Posts a message to the message queue of the MailboxProcessor, asynchronously.

Note - `Post` makes no gurantees about processing - that is the whole idea behind async.  If you need to wait for the computation to finish you need to use `PostAndReply` - although at this point you lose some of the benefit of multithreading.

The `MailboxProcessor` will always process the messages in order, but unless you wait for it, the messages won't have finished processing

Comment: exactly. this is at the heart of the concept. no guarantee of any kind within the async, it is control by outside, with specific commands. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As explained by John, the `Post` method simply posts the message to a mailbox for later processing. The message may be processed before something else happens on the sender thread, but it may not - this simply depends on the thread scheduling and there is no control over that.

If you want to send message to a mailbox and wait for the result, you need to use `PostAndReply` method (or, better use `PostAndAsyncReply` from asynchronous workflow to avoid blocking). Here is an example:

```
/// The message carries AsyncReplyChannel<unit>, which is used to
/// notify the caller that the message was processed.
type Message = 
  | Message of int * string * AsyncReplyChannel<unit> 

let mailbox = new MailboxProcessor<Message>(fun inbox -> 
    let rec loop count = 
        async { printfn "Message count = %d. Waiting for next message." count 
                // Receive & process the message
                let! (Message(id, contents, repl)) = inbox.Receive() 
                printfn "Message received. ID: %d Contents: %s" msg.ID msg.Contents 
                // Notify the caller that processing has finished
                repl.Reply()
                return! loop( count + 1) } 
    loop 0) 

mailbox.Start() 

// Send message and wait for reply using 'PostAndReply' method
mailbox.PostAndReply(fun chnl -> Message(0, "ABC", chnl))
mailbox.PostAndReply(fun chnl -> Message(0, "XYZ", chnl))
```

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed answer. it will be helpful for other async beginners.